# Integral of $d$ dimension Calculation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

Someone could help me to solve the following integral?

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{1-\cos(z)}{|z|^{1+\alpha}}dz.$$

I think that the result should be
$$\dfrac{\pi^{\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}{\alpha 2^{\alpha-1} \Gamma((1+\alpha)/2)},$$
but I don't know how to see it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $z \in \mathbb R^d$, what is $\cos (z)$ ??

Comment: Well, in this moment I don't know how, so I change the question for only $d=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

For $d=1$. The integrand is even, therefore
$$I=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{1-\cos z}{|z|^{1+\alpha}}dz=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos z}{z^{1+\alpha}}dz$$
Integrating by part
$$I=\frac{2}{\alpha}\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}\sin x dx=\frac{2}{\alpha}\Im\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{ix} dx$$
The last integral is known; we can also evaluate it integrating in the complex plane along the following contour:
from $r$ to $R$ along the axis $X$, then along the big quarter-circle (of the radius $R$) counter-clockwise, then along the axis $Y$ from $R$ to $r$, and finally along the small quarter-circle of radius $r$ clockwise - to the destination point. There are no singularities inside the contour, and it is easy to show that the integrals along quarter-circles $\to0$ as $R\to\infty$ and $r\to0$.

Therefore, $\oint=0$, and
$$I=-\frac{2}{\alpha}\Im\int_\infty^0 \Big(xe^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}\Big)^{-\alpha}e^{-x}idx=\frac{2}{\alpha}\Re \Big(\,i\,\Gamma(1-\alpha)e^{-\frac{\pi i\alpha}{2}}\Big)=\frac{2}{\alpha}\Gamma(1-\alpha)\cos\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}$$

On the other hand, using the reflection formula $\Gamma(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})=\frac{\pi}{\sin\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}}\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2})}$ and duplication formula $\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2})\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{1}{2})=2^{1-\alpha}\sqrt\pi\Gamma(\alpha)$
$$\dfrac{\pi^{\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}{\alpha 2^{\alpha-1} \Gamma((1+\alpha)/2)}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\alpha2^{\alpha-1}}\frac{\pi}{\sin\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2})}\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{1}{2})}=\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\sin\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\frac{2\cos\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}}{\Gamma(\alpha)2\sin\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}}=\frac{2\cos\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}}{\alpha}\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(\alpha)\sin\pi\alpha}=\frac{2}{\alpha}\Gamma(1-\alpha)\cos\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}$$